# Refresh ListView with LazyAdapter in Android

Tags: android, listview, lazylist

I am developing one application in that put all data in listview whatever coming from server for that i am using lazyadapter.Now i want to refresh all data in the listview(whenever click the button remove current data and update only new data i.e coming from server).i am using `notifyDataSetChanged().`its not working.please help me

My code:

```
Activity

   public class JamLocationsActivity extends Activity   {


     private ListView listView;
    private String[] imageUrls;
    private ArrayList<String> imagesArray;
    private ArrayList<String> descArray;
    private ArrayList<String> dateTimeArray;
    private ArrayList<String> titleArray;
    private ArrayList<String> userArray;
    private LazyAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> latlngArray;
    private RecieveDataDTO receivingDatDto;
    private Button btn;
    private static ImageLoader imageLoader;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
             bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
             bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
             bar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
            bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")));
            imageUrls=Constants.IMAGES;

            getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
            getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar_jamlocation);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_jam_locations);

           imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

           JamLocationsActivity.imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this));

            imagesArray   = 
          (ArrayList<String>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("imgArry");
            descArray     = 
           (ArrayList<String>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("descArry");
            dateTimeArray = 
           (ArrayList<String>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("dateTimeArry");
            titleArray    = 
           (ArrayList<String>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("titleArr");
            userArray     = 
          (ArrayList<String>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("userArr");
            latlngArray   =(ArrayList<HashMap<String, 
          String>>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("latlngArr");
            Log.e("ARRAY", latlngArray.toString());

             receivingDatDto = new RecieveDataDTO();
            receivingDatDto.setImageArr(imagesArray);
            receivingDatDto.setTitleArr(titleArray);
            receivingDatDto.setUserArr(userArray);
            receivingDatDto.setDateTimeArr(dateTimeArray);
            receivingDatDto.setDescArr(descArray);
        //receivingDatDto.setLatLngArr(latlngArray);
         adapter = new LazyAdapter(JamLocationsActivity.this,receivingDatDto);


        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                               adapter.clearAdapter();
                  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }
```

LazyAdapter

```
 public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    static Context context;
     private TextView timeTextView;
     private ListView listView;


    private String imageurl[]=null;
    private ArrayList<String> imgUrl;
    private ArrayList<String> images;
    private ArrayList<String> users;
    private ArrayList<String> dateTimes;
    private ArrayList<String> titles;
    private ArrayList<String> descriptions;
    private  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> latlngs;

    DisplayImageOptions doption=null;
    private ImageLoadingListener animateFirstListener =null;
    RecieveDataDTO receivedata= new RecieveDataDTO();




    // static ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    public LazyAdapter(Context c,RecieveDataDTO dto){
        context=c;
        //this.imageurl=url;
    //  this.imgUrl = url;
        this.images = dto.getImageArr();
        this.users = dto.getUserArr();
        this.descriptions=dto.getDescArr();
        this.dateTimes=dto.getDateTimeArr();
        this.titles=dto.getTitleArr();
        this.latlngs=dto.getLatLngArr();



    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //return imageurl.length;
        return users.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view=convertView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        Log.e("ADAPTER", images.toString());
        //viewHolder.mydate = 
      java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        AQuery androidAQuery = new AQuery(context);
        if(convertView==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context. 
           getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_data_list, null);
         viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.shareBtn=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.shareBtn);
        viewHolder.mapButton=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.reportBtn);
        viewHolder.imageView2=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        viewHolder.imageView1=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);



         animateFirstListener = new AnimateFirstDisplayListener();
         viewHolder.addressTxtView=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.adddTextId);
         viewHolder.headTextView  = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.headTextId);
         viewHolder.dateTextView=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dateTextId);
         viewHolder.userTextView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         view.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else{
            viewHolder=(ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        }
         if(images.get(position).equals("")){
             viewHolder.imageView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         }
         else{
        androidAQuery.id(viewHolder.imageView2).image(images.get(position), true, true);
             /*ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
             imageLoader.displayImage(images.get(position), viewHolder.imageView2, 
          animateFirstListener);*/
         }
        // androidAQuery.id(viewHolder.imageView2).image(Constants.IMAGES[position], true, 
          true);
         viewHolder.addressTxtView.setText(descriptions.get(position));
         viewHolder.dateTextView.setText(dateTimes.get(position));
         viewHolder.headTextView.setText(titles.get(position));
         viewHolder.userTextView.setText(users.get(position));
         if(users.get(position).equals("police")){

        viewHolder.imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.common_signin_btn_icon_dark);
         }
         else{

       viewHolder.imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.common_signin_btn_icon_light);
         }
        /* ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
         imageLoader.displayImage("", viewHolder.imageView2);
         imageLoader.displayImage(imgUrl.get(position), viewHolder.imageView2, animateFirstListener);*/

        viewHolder.shareBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,AndroidFacebookSample.class);
                intent.putExtra("fbVal", descriptions.get(position));
                intent.putExtra("trTime", dateTimes.get(position));
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        viewHolder.mapButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,SingleJamLocationActivity.class);

                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        viewHolder.imageView2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.e("You", "Clicked Me");
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ImagePerActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("imageurlpostion", images);
                intent.putExtra("imagepostion", position);
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });


        return view;
    }
    private static class AnimateFirstDisplayListener extends SimpleImageLoadingListener {

        static final List<String> displayedImages = Collections.synchronizedList(new 
      LinkedList<String>());

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            if (loadedImage != null) {
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
                boolean firstDisplay = !displayedImages.contains(imageUri);
                if (firstDisplay) {
                    FadeInBitmapDisplayer.animate(imageView, 500);
                    displayedImages.add(imageUri);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: check this link 
http://sharedstate.net/archives/pull-to-refresh

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem. Came to this solution, try it.
The only problem is that the listview will blink on refresh...

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Parcelable state = listview.onSaveInstanceState();  //save listview position
    adapter = new LazyAdapter(JamLocationsActivity.this,receivingDatDto);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listview.onRestoreInstanceState(state);    //restore listview position
}
```